# CUDA driver installation on a laptop with nVidia NVS140M card

Tags: drivers, cuda

I'm trying to first figure out if my computer contains a CUDA-enabled card. It has an nVidia NVS 140M card, but I can't seem to figure out if it is the 128 MB version or 256 MB version. On the laptop purchase receipt, I found out that I ordered the 128 MB version, but the control panel description of the card said otherwise.

When I ran the CUDA driver from nVidia's site, it could not find a hardware compatible with CUDA (even though the product series is CUDA-enabled, the card does not have 256 MB minimum of memory to do so). What would be your recommendations in this case with trying to use CUDA on this computer (I'm not sure if nothing can be done at this point)?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but your laptop manufacturer may have modified the hardware, causing problems for the driver's hardware detection:

http://en.community.dell.com/forums/p/19246530/19387853.aspx#19422716

(The link is about a similar card to yours).  Perhaps contact the laptop manufacturer about this?

Comment: I have actually solved the problem by using a workaround.

Comment: Please share the workaround. I have similar issue with my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA are recently updated their notebook compatible drivers adding support for more notebooks as the notebook manufacturers come on board with the idea. What manufacturer is your laptop? Maybe they're not on board yet! There is a recent update so you could try that.

A slightly less ideal solution, if your manufacturer is not supported, would be to try [modding the inf file](http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/) but clearly that is not a supported route!